# Horizontal content slider with previous and next arrows on top right using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi All i want to build a simple custom horizontal content slider with just two links on top as Previous and Next to slide the content using jQuery,html and css. I want it to place in the sidebar in a small area of just 300 X 300 size which contains some information divided into different sections means in different content divs which needs to be slided. I searched a lot on it but i am getting lot of plugins for this. I dont want a plugin for this I want to achieve this using clean code using jquery. Because the content in the sliding divs may be loaded with ajax content. So I want a script which is more customizable. Please help me I want it in one of my current project.

Comment: too many `wants` in the question

Comment: and no effort made at research. Try something then post a specific question not just a request to have software written for free

Comment: No guys I apologize. Its not that i have not done any effort in searching. I got lot of solutions but most of them were image sliders and they were in plugin formats. But my need was simple just to slide some divs horizontally. So I posted my question. Because I thought if I use a plugin solution then it will be difficult for me to customize and fill dynamic data by Ajax requests. But I can understand. I am still new to stackoverflow community. I will surely follow your advice next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need to customize this if you want to do ajax requests to fill in the data but [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/fx24R/5/) the gist of it.

Comment: Awesome Interstellar_Coder. I exactly wanted like this. I will definitely customize this for fill the data using Ajax requests. I wanted how exactly the sliding logic works and you have given me an excellent solution. This will surely going to help me. You rocks.

Comment: User please mark this as answered, the check mark under the 0. Thank you

Comment: Sorry Interstellar_Coder I am new to this forum so did not knew about it. Now I have checked it. Thanks once again.